# Select items from List A where the property is not in List B

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<Broadcast>` and the `Broadcast` object has a property called `Guid`. Now I need to find all `Broadcast` objects in that list whose `Guid` property is not an item in `List<Guid>`.
I've found a solution with `Except();` but it's not working for me.

```
Broadcasts.Where(x => x.Guid).Except(readBroadcasts);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way you can do it :

```
List<Guid> excludeGuid = ..... // You init guids you want to exclude
List<Broadcast> result = Broadcasts.Where(x => !excludeGuid.Contains(x.Guid)).ToList() ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
Broadcasts.Where(x => !List.Contains(x.Guid))....
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`List.FindAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
List<Broadcast> notInGuidList = Broadcasts.FindAll(b => !readBroadcasts.Contains(b.Guid));
```

Another more verbose but possibly more efficient way is a ["Left-Outer-Join"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx) with LINQ:

```
var notFound = from bc in Broadcasts
               join guid in readBroadcasts
               on bc.Guid equals guid into gj
               from guidJoin in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
               where guidJoin == default(Guid)
               select bc;
List<Broadcast> notFoundBroadCasts = notFound.ToList();
```